# Change the spawned process name for Python multiprocessing manager

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I want to change the process name of the spawned multiprocessing's manager SyncManager using setproctitle, I tried extending multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager:

```
class MySyncManager(multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MySyncManager, self).__init__()
        self.daemon=True

    def run(self):
        setproctitle.setproctitle('MySyncManager')
        super(MySyncManager, self).run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mySyncManager = MySyncManager()
    mySyncManager.start()
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Found out in the documentation of multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager which SyncManager is a subclass of: 
start([initializer[, initargs]])

    Start a subprocess to start the manager. If initializer is not None then the subprocess will call initializer(*initargs) when it starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my question.

```
def changeProcessTitle(title):
    from setproctitle import setproctitle
    setproctitle(title)

class MySyncManager(multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MySyncManager, self).__init__()
        self.daemon=True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mySyncManager = MySyncManager()
    initArgs = ('MySyncManager', )
    mySyncManager.start(changeProcessTitle, initArgs)
```